# Find on page in Google Chrome by simply typing on page

Tags: google-chrome, find

Is there a way to "find on page" without typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>?

Firefox offers this functionality, but not Google Chrome, as far as Preferences tells me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ["type-ahead-find" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpecbmjeidppdiampimghndkikcmoadk) allows Chrome to search in your current page without your hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> on Macs).

Features:

> - Start writing (or press <kbd>/</kbd>) to start text search.
> - Press <kbd>'</kbd> to search only links.
> - Change option "direct search state" to set the default search policy (text, links or disabled).
> - Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>/<kbd>P</kbd> to switch between matches.
> - Use <kbd>F4</kbd> to toggle matching mode (text/links) once the search is active.
> - Blacklist sites that set up their own shortcuts.
> - The search shows first matches in current viewport.

Comment: FYI: I've copy-edited your post a bit for clarity. (By the way, your name is hilarious :p)